# Kafka Streams Application Reset Tool not deleting internal topics

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am facing problems with using the Application Reset Tool in Kafka Streams. Kafka streams creates internal topics for my streams which have a config property **cleanup.policy** that defaults to **delete** for repartition topic and **compact** for changelog topic. But I am noticing that in one of our development environments the topics do not have these configs. And as such the reset tool does not delete these topics. Even when I manually alter the config for these topics it reverts back to no config for some of them. Any idea what might be happening. Its a weird behavior that just started on its own. I am running Kafka 1.0

Comment: The reset tool does not consider any configs when deleting topics, but looks for naming patterns. Thus, there must be some other issue. The question is, why does the config get's changes back? Kafka Streams does not alter configs if topic exists but only create new topics with specific config setting -- if a topic exists, Streams does not check the setting but assumes that the configs are as expected.

Comment: What I am noticing is that the topics that don't have a cleanup.policy are the ones that aren't deleted by the tool. Hence my conjecture. Any idea why the config maybe changing. I am using connect to load data from db. Do some joins in Streams and then output to ES using sink connector. I have stopped connect and the streams application during reset but the issue persists. Also is there a way to force delete a topic

Comment: Not sure. It seems you say that some topic get deleted but others not? Because if no topic gets deleted, I would suspect that topic deletion is disabled broker side. Can you verify this?

Comment: Topic deletion is enabled. I checked the config. What happens is the topics with no policy set do not get deleted. So in my script I manually first alter the policy of all internal topics and then run the reset. But incredibly some of those altered topics revert back to their original no config and hence dont get deleted. Its incredibly bewildering and frustrating

Comment: I would check the broker logs and enable logging client side, too. Not sure if this dev cluster is shared? Could there be some other application or zombie process that this messing with you?

Comment: Nothing really sticks out in the broker logs but I'll investigate further. While an application can connect to the cluster I dont expect it to happen and unfortunately my dev-ops knowledge isnt quite upto par to investigate it deeply. But i'll look into it. Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it

Comment: Out of curiosity -- if I shut down my kafka cluster, delete all the topic logs and then bring back the cluster again would it wipe out all the old topics?

Comment: Yes. The topic metadata is stored in Zookeeper directory though, thus you also need to stop ZK and wipe out this part.

Comment: @Fizi did you manage to figure this out? We're experiencing the same issue

Comment: @omer Hi I think we did manage to have a fix/workaround but its so old that I dont quite remember :(